# Wordpress contact form 7 not showing any response

Tags: wordpress

My forms have suddenly broken and I have just realised it, as upon clicking nothing is happening. No errors or anything, its just that nothing happens when clicked. I could go to a restore point but the problem is I don't know when this issue occurred. I have updated all my plugins as well.

Here is the form code:

```
<div class="steps" id="step1">
<span class="heading">How would you describe yourself?</span>
[radio liviti_user_type  id:selectUserType class:radio-style-1 use_label_element "First Home Buyer" "Next Home Buyer" "Investor" "Property Industry"]
<input type="hidden" id="flowid">
[hidden liviti_user_hash id:liviti_user_hash]
</div>

<div class="steps" id="step2">
<span class="heading">How many bedrooms are you looking for?</span>
[checkbox* liviti_user_bedroom id:liviti_user_bedroom use_label_element class:liviti_user_bedroom "Studio" "1 Bedroom" "2 Bedrooms" "3+ Bedrooms"]
<div class="next_prev">
<p class="back_button_wrap"><input type="button" value="Back" class="liviti_back_button btn btn-light" style="text-transform: none;" onclick="formGoBack();"></p>
<p class="continue_button_wrap"><span class='wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit formNextButton' id="goToStep3"> Next</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="steps" id="step3">
<span class="heading">What is your time frame to move in?</span>
[radio user_movein_time id:user_movein_time class:user_movein_time use_label_element  "0-6 months" "6-12 months" "12+ months"]
<div class="next_prev">
<p class="back_button_wrap"><input type="button" value="Back" style="text-transform: none;" class="liviti_back_button btn btn-light" onclick="formGoBack();"></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="steps" id="step4">
<span class="heading">What's your best email to receive all the information?</span>
<i class="leadform_email_icon fa fa-envelope"></i>[email* liviti_user_email id:liviti_user_email placeholder "Email Address"]

[hidden lead_project_name id:lead_project_name ]
[hidden lead_fname id:lead_fname]
[hidden lead_lname id:lead_lname]
[hidden lead_phone id:lead_phone]
[hidden lead_bedroom id:lead_bedroom ]

<div class="next_prev"><p class="back_button_wrap"><input type="button" value="Back" style="text-transform: none;" class="liviti_back_button btn btn-light" onclick="formGoBack();"></p><p class="continue_button_wrap" style="text-transform: none;">[submit id:submit_user_email "Continue"]</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? You can also set debug mode to true if there are any php errors. And have you tried to create another simple form with just a few fields to check if this is working? You need to get more information, otherwise it will be hard to find out why it is not working anymore.